# Why is the list of "Hot Network Questions" not consistent?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

As I browse around pretty much anywhere in Stack Exchange, I can't help but notice that the list of "Hot Network Questions" doesn't seem to be consistent.  Not only is the order not consistent between different SE pages, the content of the list itself is not always the same.

#### Is it meant to be randomized like this, and if so, why?

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be random on every page load.

Comment: Cheers, and the reason is given in the dupe, to increase traffic.